# Combining / Merging Virtual Machines

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012

I have 3 virtual machines (OS installed: Ubuntu Server) on my Hyper V. I want to combine / merge these 3 virtual machines into one virtual machine. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have no clear idea what you mean by this.

If it sounds like I think it does, then the answer is "No." Separate OS instances are separate, whether they're VMs or physical. You can't "merge" them.

You could identify the services that each provides and then migrate each of those services into a single machine, by installing the software and copying the data/configs over to the single machine. Again, this is no different on physical or VM.